# What are argument types for fit() function in keras?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras

According to the [Keras](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) documentation:

```
fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, ...)
```

The arguments for fit function are numpy arrays:

Arguments

> x: Numpy array of training data (if the model has a single input), or
>   list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple inputs). If input
>   layers in the model are named, you can also pass a dictionary mapping
>   input names to Numpy arrays. x can be None (default) if feeding from
>   framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow data tensors).
>
> y: Numpy array of target (label) data (if the model has a single
>   output), or list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple outputs).
>   If output layers in the model are named, you can also pass a
>   dictionary mapping output names to Numpy arrays. y can be None
>   (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow
>   data tensors).

But I can pass `x` and `y` as dataframe and series.

```
print(type(x_train))
print(type(y_train))
```

> **Output:**
>
> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
> ```

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, ..)
```

This works fine. Why is that?

Comment: because author was clever and added this functionality. `pandas` uses `numpy` so it is easy to convert dataframe to array - `df.as_matrix()`

Comment: Thanks, can we view source code to see that? just curious because the documentation doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this case has been covered in Keras source code by standardizing the input data in [these lines](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c10d24959b0ad615a21e671b180a1b2466d77a2b/keras/engine/training.py#L1084-L1089):

```
    # Case 2: Symbolic tensors or Numpy array-like.
    x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_user_data(
        x, y,
        sample_weight=sample_weight,
        class_weight=class_weight,
        batch_size=batch_size)
```

The `_standardize_user_data` method calls `standardize_input_data` function which converts DataFrame to Numpy array using using `.values` attribute of DataFrame in [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c10d24959b0ad615a21e671b180a1b2466d77a2b/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L93):

```
    data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
```

As for `Series`, this is done a bit more implicitly in `standardize_single_array` function in [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/30fe4ff1f12ff0c45bac8738b4d2690eadd056b2/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L30):

```
    elif x.ndim == 1:
        x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, same goes for pandas series?